# Internal dependencies for automake build system

Tags: autotools, automake

I've following structure of my project:

```
|
|---libs
|    |---lib1
|    |---lib2
|
|---lib3
```

And dependencies:

- lib1 depends on lib3
- lib3 depends on lib2

So automake should build libraries in the following order: lib2, lib3, lib1
My question is(I know that this library should be redesigned first, but assume, it can't be): is it possible to defined dependencies in Makefile.am, to build this project properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sticking with a recursive directory structure, you can control the order of descent with the `SUBDIRS` variable. This is fine for things like separate library and test directories; the "Recursive Make Considered Harmful" catch-all overstates the case. In *this* case, though, it's sound advice. You obviously realise this - so can it be done?

Top level `Makefile.am` use:

```
SUBDIRS = libs/lib2 lib3 libs/lib1
```

This 'works' - but it means *no* `libs/Makefile.am`. So if you were linking them all together as a convenience (`noinst_LTLIBRARIES`) library or installed library, you would need to handle this at the top level.

In theory, I suppose you could add `libs` as the last directory. But I have my doubts that this would work, e.g., `make dist` - and it would be madness anyway. It's best just to pretend this paragraph was never written.

Comment: Hmm, I wanted to avoid using the only one Makefile.am with SUBDIRS = libs/lib2 lib3 libs/lib1. But it seems it's the only one solution. Thanks anyway ;)